# Unusual Terminology in Hartigan's DIP paper?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology

In [Hartigan's DIP test paper](http://www.stat.washington.edu/wxs/Stat593-s03/Literature/hartigan85a.pdf), it says

> A distribution function $F$ is unimodal with mode $m$ if $F$ is convex in $(-\infty,m]$ and concave in $[m,\infty)$.

Shouldn't that be a *cumulative* distribution function?  Either I'm profoundly misunderstanding something, or, by that definition, a Gaussian PDF is not unimodal, because it is neither convex nor concave left or right of the mode:

[image: Gaussian function neither convex nor concave]

On the other hand, the CDF of a Gaussian does seem to fulfill that criterion. Not knowing which Hartigan and Hartigan are talking about makes the paper and the algorithm they explain hard to understand.

Comment: There are many precedents for not adding the word "cumulative" in the literature. By chance I am just reading Harold Jeffreys, _Theory of probability_ Oxford U.P. 1961 who does precisely that. But you can insert it validly.

Comment: "distribution function" without any other adjective would normally be taken to refer to the CDF. The thing you've drawn is the density, not the distribution. I'd say that terminology wasn't really unusual.

Comment: Note that a unimodal probability density function is quasiconcave and that many probability densities used in practice (e.g. the normal) are log concave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [quite common](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) to drop the "cumulative". There should be no danger of confusion with the probability *density* function.